# login method dosnt work after some changes

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

How should I change login logic to consider "mobile" field instead of "email" using *Laravel 5.8*?

I changed *email* field to *mobile* but the login method (register is ok) always returns false response.

User model :

```
namespace App;


use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;


    protected $fillable = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'profile_image', 'mobile', 'mobile_verified_at', 'email', 'email_verified_at', 'province_id', 'city_id', 'zone_id', 'status', 'wallet', 'offer_code', 'offer_percent', 'job', 'password');


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token','role_id'
    ];

    protected $username = 'mobile';


    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


    public function username()
    {
        return 'mobile';
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($value);
    }



}
```

LoginController :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Validate the user login request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'mobile'    => 'required|exists:users,mobile',
            'password'  => 'required|min:3',
            'captcha'   => 'required|captcha'
        ]);

    }

}
```

Login View :

```
{{--@extends('layouts.app')--}}
@extends('site::layout.template')

@section('content')

    <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">

                <!-- Card header-->
                <div class="card-header max">
                    <h3>Login</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">

                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-8">

                            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <label>Mobile</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control form-shadow @error('mobile') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('mobile') }}"  placeholder="09121234567" >
                                        @error('mobile')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <label>Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-shadow @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="*********" >
                                        @error('password')
                                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                                Remember me
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>




                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-shadow @error('captcha') is-invalid @enderror" name="captcha" placeholder="enter front code" >
                                        @error('captcha')
                                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <img  id="refresh" class="captcha" src="{!! captcha_src('flat') !!}" alt="">
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">ورود</button>
                                </div>
                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                      Reset password ?
                                    </a>
                                @endif

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

@endsection
```

The captcha is okey and works fine. I now need to change the login method from "email" to "mobile".

Comment: any body can help ?

Answer (score 0):

in Auth/LoginController just add
function username()

```
 public function username()
{
    return 'email';
}
```

then replace the email of what u want.

Comment: Also, you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qtiyo2J_-tA&feature=youtu.be) video

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#included-authenticating).

> #### Username Customization
>
> By default, Laravel uses the email field for authentication. If you would like to >customize this, you may define a username method on your LoginController:
>
> ```php
> public function username()
> {
>    return 'username';
> }
> ```

So, in your case you have to add this function in your `LoginController` and change `username` into mobile:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'mobile';
    }

    /**
     * Validate the user login request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'mobile'    => 'required|exists:users,mobile',
            'password'  => 'required|min:3',
            'captcha'   => 'required|captcha'
        ]);

    }

}
```

If you need a more dynamic logic, than you should have a look at the source code of the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait, and override the login function.